# how can we find the xor of elements of an array over the range l,r with a given number x provided there are multiple queries of such type?

Tags: optimization, data-structures

For the above questioned i went through some of the query optimization techniques like square root decomposition , binary indexed tree but they don't help in solving my problem optimally . If anybody can suggest an query optimization technique through which i can solve this problem please do suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in constant time, using a `O(n)` space, where `n` is the size of your array. The initial construction takes `O(n)`.
Given an array `A`, you first need to build the array `XOR-A`, in this way:

```
XOR-A[0] = A[0]
For i from 1 to n-1:
  XOR-A[i] = XOR-A[i-1] xor A[i]
```

Then you can answer a query on the range (l, r) as follows:

```
get_xor_range(l, r, XOR-A):
  return XOR-A[l-1] xor XOR-A[r]
```

We use the fact that for any `x`, `x xor x = 0`. That's what makes the job here.

Edit: Sorry I did not understand the problem well at first.
Here is a method to update the array in `O(m + n)` time, and `O(n)` space, where `n` is the size of the array and `m` the number of queries.
Notation: the array is `A`, of size `n`, the queries are `(l_i, r_i, x_i), 0 <= i < m`

```
L <- array of tuple (l_i, x_i) sorted in ascending order by the l_i 
R <- array of tuple (r_i, x_i) sorted in ascending order by the r_i
X <- array initialised at 0 everywhere, of size `n`
idx <- 0
l, x <- L[idx]
for j from 0 to n-1 do:
  while l == j do:
    X[j] <- X[j] xor x
    idx ++
    l, x <- L[idx]
  if j < n then X[j+1] <- X[j]

idx <- 0
r, x <- R[idx]
for j from 0 to n-1 do:
  while r == j do:
    X[j] <- X[j] xor x
    idx ++
    r, x <- R[idx]
  if j < n then X[j+1] <- X[j]

for j from 0 to n-1 do:
  A[j] <- A[j] xor X[j]
```

Comment: my question is if i have a query of type l r x where l = lower limit , r = upper limit and x = number i need to answer this type of query multiple times .For example my array is 2 2 2 and my query is 1 3 4 i need to xor all the elements of array with 4 then my array gets updated to 6 6 6.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I did not read the question well. When you mean multiple queries, do you mean multiple queries with the same `x`, or multiple queries with the same `(l,r)`, or none of both ?

Comment: multiple queries with different (l,r) and different x in each query,no. of queries >10^6 so some may be repeated not sure about it

Comment: Then I don't think that it is possible to 'optimize' anything, since the size of your output should be `sum(r_i - l_i)`, and that a simple algorithm (`for each query: for j from l_i to r_i do ....`) would also run in `sum(r_i - l_i)`. Or do you only need to update your array ? If only update then there is room for optimisation

Comment: yes i need to update the array for each l,r,x query i need the resultant array after queries

Comment: Have a look, I updated the answer with a 'linear time' solution

Comment: thanks for the information and apologies for the late reply